# OpenLDAP: rfc2307bis instead of nis schema

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap

I'm looking for a way to create an empty LDAP dictionary with the rfc2307bis schema. On Debian when installing slapd or when reconfiguring with dpkg the nis schema is used by default.
How do I remove it or replace it with rfc2307bis ? At initialization or after.

Answer (score 2):

After initialization, list the loaded schemas:

```
# ldapsearch -LLL -Y external -H ldapi:/// -b cn=schema,cn=config -s one dn
[...]
dn: cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
[...]
```

Remove the NIS schema:

```
# ldapdelete -Y external -H ldapi:/// cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
```

Add the other one:

```
# ldapadd -Y external -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/rfc2307bis.ldif
```

Comment: I just tried and I cannot remove the nis schema:
-
`ldapdelete -Y external cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config` -> Unknown authentication method (-6)
-
`ldapdelete -Y external -H ldapi:/// cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config` -> Server is unwilling to perform (53)

Comment: Right, I didn't remember correctly. There is some experimental delete support in the config database code (search for `SLAP_CONFIG_DELETE`). But it's inactive and probably neglected. Thus you can't remove a schema *properly*. You can remove directories under `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema` after stopping `slapd`, but that's [unsupported](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7003257).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.
I edited this file: /usr/share/slapd/slapd.init.ldif and replaced a line:

```
#include: file:///etc/ldap/schema/nis.ldif
include: file:///etc/ldap/schema/rfc2307bis.ldif
```

And I ran dpkg-reconfigure slapd.

Comment: Note that your modifications to `/usr/share/slapd/slapd.init.ldif` will be lost on any upgrade of the *slapd* package. Modifying package files (except conffiles) is not supported.

Comment: That's not a problem, that is just for the creation of the database